# gitkraken not showing screen after installation

Tags: linux-mint, gitkraken

I have installed GitKraken 3.3.4 on my LinuxMint 18.1-64 bit machine. I When I click on GitKraken it shows loading, but display is not showing up in the screen. Anyone can help me to solve this issue?.

No issues in installation using command line or package installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Above command is the solution for my problem. For more details [refer this reddit page with details](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/6gzkc5/gitkraken_installs_but_fails_to_start/)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install libgnome-keyring0
```

Solved my problem.